# Step-by-Step Tutorial for JQuery Plugin Smooth Div Scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, smooth-scrolling

I am knew to JQuery and am looking for a step-by-step tutorial for the [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/). I am interested in adding this feature to a page in Wordpress.

These are the steps as I understand them:

(1) Add the following script in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll();
});
</script>
```

(2) Add css to main style sheet.

(3) Add code to page

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
<div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft"></div>
<div class="scrollingHotSpotRight"></div>
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<div class="scrollableArea">
<img src="images/demo/image_1.jpg" width="400" height="200" />
<img src="images/demo/image_2.jpg" width="350" height="200" />
<img src="images/demo/image_3.jpg" width="545" height="200" />
<img src="images/demo/image_4.jpg" width="400" height="200" />
<img src="images/demo/image_5.jpg" width="600" height="200" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is how i got it to work!

**Just inside my "head" tag i added**

```
 <style type="text/css">
      #makeMeScrollable
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 330px;
        position: relative;
    }

     #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>
```

**Secondly i added this to page!**

```
<!-- LOAD JAVASCRIPT LATE - JUST BEFORE THE BODY TAG 
     That way the browser will have loaded the images
     and will know the width of the images. No need to
     specify the width in the CSS or inline. -->

<!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI Widget and Effects Core (custom download)
     You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Latest version of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
     You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.2 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
     js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.2.js -->


<!-- Plugin initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({});
    });
</script>
```

The options i set is to override the defaults!

Then i go to my CSS and add this

```
    /* Invisible left hotspot */
    div.scrollingHotSpotLeft
    {
/* The hotspots have a minimum width of 100 pixels and if there is room the will grow
    and occupy 15% of the scrollable area (30% combined). Adjust it to your own taste. */
min-width: 75px;
width: 10%;
height: 100%;
/* There is a big background image and it's used to solve some problems I experienced
in Internet Explorer 6. */
background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center center;
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
left: 0;
/*  The first url is for Firefox and other browsers, the second is for Internet Explorer */
cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.png), url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.cur),w-resize;
   }

  /* Visible left hotspot */
  div.scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible
   {
background-image: url(../images/arrow_left.gif);                
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
opacity: 0.35; /* Standard CSS3 opacity setting */
-moz-opacity: 0.35; /* Opacity for really old versions of Mozilla Firefox (0.9 or older) */
filter: alpha(opacity = 35); /* Opacity for Internet Explorer. */
zoom: 1; /* Trigger "hasLayout" in Internet Explorer 6 or older versions */
    }

   /* Invisible right hotspot */
   div.scrollingHotSpotRight
 {
min-width: 75px;
width: 10%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center center;
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
right: 0;
cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.png), url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur),e-resize;
    }

    /* Visible right hotspot */
    div.scrollingHotSpotRightVisible
    {
background-image: url(../images/arrow_right.gif);
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
opacity: 0.35;
filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
-moz-opacity: 0.35;
zoom: 1;
    }

     /* The scroll wrapper is always the same width and height as the containing element (div).
   Overflow is hidden because you don't want to show all of the scrollable area.
   */
   div.scrollWrapper
   {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
   }

   div.scrollableArea
   {
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
   }
```

Lastly i added this over the javscript but under head tag

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="images/demo/field.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="field" />
    <img src="images/demo/gnome.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="gnome" />
    <img src="images/demo/pencils.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="pencils" />
    <img src="images/demo/golf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="golf" />
    <img src="images/demo/river.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="river" />
    <img src="images/demo/train.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="train" />
    <img src="images/demo/leaf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="leaf" />
    <img src="images/demo/dog.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="dog" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from jquery smooth page 
put inside head tags this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
            mousewheelScrolling: true,
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
            autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in the body somewhere where you want to show these images

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
        <img src="images/demo/field.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="field" />
        <img src="images/demo/gnome.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="gnome" />
        <img src="images/demo/pencils.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="pencils" />
        <img src="images/demo/golf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="golf" />
        <img src="images/demo/river.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="river" />
        <img src="images/demo/train.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="train" />
        <img src="images/demo/leaf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="leaf" />
        <img src="images/demo/dog.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="dog" />
</div>
```